# Returning individual vertices of get.shortest.paths() in R

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I have created a random (Erdos-Renyi) graph with p = 0.2 and 10 nodes in R using the igraph package like this:

```
library(igraph)
graph <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.2, type = c("gnp", "gnm"), directed = FALSE,
    loops = FALSE)
```

I find the central node and leaf nodes of the graph like this:

```
centralNode <- which(degree(graph) %in% c(max(degree(graph))))
leafNodes <- which(degree(graph) %in% c(1))
```

I find the shortest path from the central node to the first leaf node like this:

```
sp <- get.shortest.paths(graph, centralNode, leafNodes[1])
```

And can get something like this (if 1 is the `centralNode` and 4 is the `leafNodes[1]`:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1  2  9  4
```

I want to be able to access each of the vertices in the shortest path from the `centralNode` to the `leafNodes[1]`.

I tried doing it like this but keep getting these errors:

```
sp$2
    Error: unexpected numeric constant in "sp$2"
sp$[[1]][2]
    Error: unexpected '[[' in "sp$[["
sp$1[2]
    Error: unexpected numeric constant in "sp$1"
sp$[1][2]
    Error: unexpected '[' in "sp$["
```

I'm not sure how to return each vertex individually, or just pick one of them. I hope this makes sense.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp` is just a standard list. So `sp[[1]]` etc will work to just get a vector.

However, it probably makes more sense for you to be subsetting the graph object. Something like this:

```
V(graph)[sp[[1]]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to return all of the paths from one node to another, not just the shortest path?

Comment: Not with igraph. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668466/all-paths-between-2-vertexes-in-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971876/all-possible-paths-from-one-node-to-another-in-a-directed-tree-igraph